# C++ Tokenize String

Tags: c++, string, split, std, tokenize

I'm looking for a simple way to tokenize `std::string` input without using non default libraries such as Boost, etc.

For example, if the user enters forty_five, I would like to separate 'forty' and 'five' using the '_' as the delimiter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/240633

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To convert a string to a vector of tokens (thread safe):

```
std::vector<std::string> inline StringSplit(const std::string &source, const char *delimiter = " ", bool keepEmpty = false)
{
    std::vector<std::string> results;

    size_t prev = 0;
    size_t next = 0;

    while ((next = source.find_first_of(delimiter, prev)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        if (keepEmpty || (next - prev != 0))
        {
            results.push_back(source.substr(prev, next - prev));
        }
        prev = next + 1;
    }

    if (prev < source.size())
    {
        results.push_back(source.substr(prev));
    }

    return results;
}
```

Comment: +1 Much more appealing than than the strstream stuff I linked to.

Comment: Works like a charm. Using `const string &delimiter` for the second parameter appears to work too.

Answer (score 2):

**C++20**

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <ranges>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::string input{ "C++20 Tokenization Example" };

    for (const auto& token_range : input | std::views::split(' ')) {
        std::string token{};
        std::ranges::copy(token_range, std::back_inserter(token));
        std::cout << token << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Outpot:

```
C++20
Tokenization
Example
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/S9xxearjzH)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [strtok_r](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) function, but read the man pages carefully so you understand how it maintains state.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/split/) tutorial, which is by far the best tutorial on tokenization that I have found so far. It covers the best practices in the implementation of different methods that include using **getline()** and **find_first_of()** in C++ std, and **strtok()** in C.