# C++ How would I read a file into an multidimensional array or three seperate arrays based on a sequence of delimiters?

Tags: c++, arrays, delimiter

New to c++ and programming, and I am having trouble figuring this out.

Pseudo idea; 
Assuming I can define the delimiters

```
 ',' ',' '\n'
```

then read file line by line
while adding each element to each array.

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 1000 

string someString[ARRAY_SIZE];
double someDoubble[ARRAY_SIZE];
double someDoubble[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

Then the text file that I am reading is

```
somestring, someDouble, someDouble\n
```

Or in other words the delimiters are comma, comma, newline char.

Comment: Are you finding difficulties in reading file or tokenizing the read line based on delimeter ?

Comment: No issues reading the file line by line, Just I have no clue on how to tokenizing the read line by delimiter in c++

Comment: [Tokenize a string based on delimeter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051679/c-tokenize-string).

Comment: Thank you for your input! Due to my level of knowledge, the function that is listed makes no sense to me, and leaves me wondering how would I use that to get my data into an array. The language I am strongest in is bash, and I am really new to c++. Could you illuminate for me how you see this being applicable, to what I am asking? Sorry, it seems a bit over my head.

Comment: @BrianDanielPemberton see the edit. It has been approved now.

Answer (score 1):

if you are very sure about the delimiter and the count, then you may use

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream fs;
    fs.open("abc.txt",ios::in);         //1
    string str;
    int counter = 0;
    vector<string> vecString;
    vector<double> vecDouble1;
    vector<double> vecDouble2;
    while(getline(fs, str))             //2
    {
        char *sArr = new char[str.length()+1];          //3
        strcpy(sArr, str.c_str());
        char *pch = strtok(sArr,",");                   //4
        vecString.push_back(pch);                       //5
        pch = strtok(NULL,",");
        vecDouble1.push_back(atof(pch));                //6
        pch = strtok(NULL,",");
        vecDouble2.push_back(atof(pch));
        delete[] sArr;                                  //7
    }
    cin.ignore();
}
```

I would advise you to use arrays over vectors.

Explanation on demand:

1. Opens a text file in input mode via stream
2. Gets text from file line by line.
3. This intermediate char array is used as it is unsafe to cast a `const` to non `const.
4. Tokenizes the input line based on the delimiters(a singlecomma in your case). Refer [THIS](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/25408/) for tutorial.
5. Adds the element to vector at the end.
6. `atof()` is used to convert `string` to `double`.
7. Free out the intermediate character pointer.

Comment: Thank you for you input also! Would you mind walking me trough what this code is doing so I understand what is happening?

Comment: The `fs.getline()` call in the while-expression is reading up to 100 chars of data into a string that has no allocated space at all. Therefore, #2 is a segfault waiting to happen. Likewise, `const_cast<>` is only safe if the origin of the datum passed was also non-const, which it isn't in this case. (see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357600/is-const-cast-safe)). In short, don't do it this way.

Comment: @WhozCraig I welcome your suggestion but a downvote. cmon man

Comment: Fix the code and I'll gladly not only remove it, I'll upvote it. The exiting code will more-than-likely fault on the first `getline()`. Why not use the optional delimiter parameter of `getline()` for some help? And perhaps the natural stream extraction operators for conversions of the doubles.

Comment: @WhozCraig I hope it is fine now. Any other suggestions??

Comment: Yeah. I'll lift the down vote first now that the seg-fault has been lifted. I would do this entire thing differently, but for your specific code, I would use a `std::vector<char> sArr(str.length()+1);` and probably the std lib's `std::copy()` instead of `strcpy()`. Why the vector ? [See RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). There is little reason for `new` and `delete` in most modern C++ programs. Thanks for fixing the seg-fault.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for making me LEARN