# Extracting Substrings

Tags: c++, string, substring

So I have a lab problem I need help with. I need to write a function that has a name parameter that includes the person's entire name. Ex) "John Quincy Doe". From that input, my function has to return the last name with a comma, then the first name and middle initial. Ex) "Doe, John Q". I have the right idea of checking for space and then breaking them into substrings, but how do I go about doing that in C++?

Answer (score 2):

That is commonly called tokenizing a string. There are multiple answers on here. I would just comment, but apparently I can't until I have 50 reputation.

[C++ Tokenize String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051679/c-tokenize-string)

[How do I tokenize a string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you are allowed to use it, you could also implement your function with a [regular expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) that matches three parts of the name and uses the sub matches in the correct order resp. with only the first letter of the second match, e.g. the middle name.