# c_str() produces different output when string is originally in a std::vector

Tags: c++

I am trying to token a string and I'm getting some strange behaviour.  Here is the code:

```
ifstream fin("myFile.txt");
char* in[256];
fin.getline(in,256);
string s = in;
vector<string> f;
f.push_back(s);
char* pch1,pch2;
pch1 = strtok((char*)s.c_str()," ");
pch1 = strtok(NULL," ");
pch2 = strtok((char*)f[0].c_str()," ");
pch2 = strtok(NULL," ");
```

if the file contains the line "This is a string", then the value stored at location pch1 will be "is", but pch2 will point to null.  Why is that?

I printed out the bytes of the two strings, s and f[0].  s contains all the characters I expect, including the space.  However, f[0] contains the 0 character instead of spaces.  I understand that sometimes istreams can treat the space as a null character, but shouldn't s and f[0] contain exactly the same bytes?

Comment: Don't use `strtok()` please when working with `std::string`.

Comment: What is this unholy mishmash of languages? Why use any ancient, often unsafe C functions when C++ goes to great pains to provide you with an extremely comprehensive and typesafe standard library? That's missing the point entirely. Please, pick one language XOR the other.

Comment: Here's a solution to your problem, Michael:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051679/c-tokenize-string .

Comment: This code won't compile.  You have declare `in` as an array of character pointers, and then written `string s = in`.  `in` will decay to `char**` and `std::string` has no constructor which takes that.

Comment: `stream`s do not treat space as a null character. Extractors stop extracting when they encounter whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the advice.  I still have a lot to learn, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

`strtok` modifies the string, it [replaces occurrences of the delimiter](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtok) with '\0'. `c_str()` returns a `const char*`, you should not simply cast the `const` away.

Comment: Yup, in all cases, modifying a `const` variable via non-`const` reference/pointer results in UB. That's probably just one of the problems with this attempt.

Answer (score 2):

You are causing all kinds of undefined behavior.  I would recommend staying away from `stroke` and instead look into boost's tokenizer library.  Your brain cells will appreciate it.  Just forget that the entire C library exists in C++ unless you really, really, really need it to talk to another C library.